# Filtering a twitter stream with ttytter and Bash scripting

Tags: bash, twitter

I am trying to filter a twitter stream that gets sent to my phone. I am doing this by using ttytter, greping and cutting the output then retweeting the results to which I follow on my phone. I  need good performance as I use it to get jobs and even 30 seconds can make the difference.

Here is the code:

```
./ttytter -ssl -dostream -noansi -hold|grep '<AirtaskerSYD>'
|grep -i -E "assemble|fix|ikea"|cut -c20-|tr "\n" "\0" 
|xargs -0 -n1 -p -I {} ./ttytter -script -status={}
```

I've gotten this far by googling, but the problem I am having is that it retweets only when you end the ./ttytter stream. Is this a limitation of pipes? Could I use 2 bash scrips, one to  append a file and the another while loop to read it, tweet it and delete the file?

Thanks,

Comment: see if `which unbuffer` returns anything. If so, put that at the very front of your command pipeline as `unbuffer ./ttytter ... ` It might fix this. Also, saw this on the main `ttytter` page "From the command line, use it to update your Twitter in shell scripts, from cron, and so on.", so maybe some poking around in their doc will yield a standard solution. Good luck.

Comment: Thank, I have worked something out. I found the --line-buffer option for grep, but it still had no effect. In the end I ended up dumping everything to a file, then having a while loop that watches for changes and applies formatting and filtering and retweets,